# Gluster volume keep disconnecting from mount point

Tags: amazon-web-services, filesystems, glusterfs

I'm using glusterFs on AWS. In particular I'm using a big instance with four ephemeral drive that I want to merge to create a unique file system.

Here what I usually do:

```
 umount /dev/xvdb
 mkfs.xfs /dev/xvdb -f
 mount /dev/xvdb /brick0

 umount /dev/xvda
 mkfs.xfs /dev/xvda -f
 mount /dev/xvdb /brick1

 gluster volume create gv0 master:/brick0 master:/brick1 force
 gluster volume start gv0
 mount.glusterfs master:/gv0 /mount/point
```

The volume starts and works correctly for few hour (quite intensive read/write operations on the volume).
However after two hours (usually, but not necessarily) the gluster volume doesn't result anymore mounted on the mount point.
Anyone already experienced this issue?
Can you help me to solve it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: The gluster community forum reports: "Transport endpoint is not connected is an error from FUSE that indicates that glusterfs was unable to serve a request for a file. Glusterfs provides no mechanism for persistent retries of failed operations (as at version 2.0). A common cause of this error is a network interruption."

Comment: So let's say that is a network error. How could I avoid it? Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You get "Transport endpoint is not connected" error when the glusterfs client process died unexpectedly. This glusterfs client process is the one that uses FUSE and provides gluster on that mount point.